# How to create random number between 2 numbers but it just change in a range?

Tags: java, random

Anybody know how to create random number between 2 numbers but it just change in a range ?

For instance, create random number between 10 - 100, with the change every time is in range [-5,+5].
Ex: if the first random is 17, the after random number will be in range [12, 22]

Thank you!

Comment: What language are you using, be more specific with questions

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How is 47 43 45 41 38 "changing every time is 5"?

Comment: Thank you. I just ask the algorithm, you can use java, make a random from 10 to 100 with condition that, the change every times just in range [-5,+5]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This algorithm picks an initial random value `x`, in range [0, 100]. After that every new random value `y` will be within 5 of the previous random value `x`.

```
    int maximum = 100;
    int minimum = 0;

    Random rn = new Random();
    int range = maximum - minimum + 1;
    int randomNum =  rn.nextInt(range) + minimum;
    System.out.println(randomNum);

    for (int i=0; i< 100; i++) {
        maximum = randomNum + 5;
        minimum = randomNum - 5;

        range = maximum - minimum + 1;
        randomNum =  rn.nextInt(range) + minimum;
        System.out.println(randomNum);
    }
```

---

Comment: That's what the code does. After 60, it will pick in range [55, 65].

Comment: Hi Martin Konecy, your code is just right for 2 firts numbers only, the third and after is not right because it call the first random. when I code in java to print out 100 random numbers satisfy the conditions, it meet the problem about pointer. The first times of the making random number function, it create a random number, but the next times, the function have to call the previous number and I dont know how to do it in java. Can you show me how to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. You can give examples, however this code will never be more than [-5, +5] after the previous number

Comment: Sorry, because I wrote function RandomNumber(int minimum, int maximum) so everytime call it, it will re-do the first action is recreating the first random number. so if I write function, it's not right.

Comment: In that case why dpn't you split the function into two, so the first part isn't always called when you call it as a function.

Comment: I tried but Java doesn't have cursor and recursion :( Could you edit your code to function. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand your question, but little bit confused with your sequence on example. This is one of the possible answer:

In java, you can generate like that:

```
Random rn = new Random();
int range = maximum - minimum + 1;
int randomNum =  rn.nextInt(range) + minimum;
```

Comment: It's not right! every times it maybe change more than 5, for instane in above rn.nextInt(91). The change is only in range [-5,+5]